# How to write a LINQ query to do this

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

```
IQueryable<SomeType> result = (from x in Context.XXX select x);
```

now what I need to do is the following (written pseudo code, I need actual code):

```
foreach(var i in items)
{
  // Where the object "i" has 2 properties
  // 1) i.Operator (values of which can be AND or OR)
  // 2) i.SomeID (values of which can be 1 .. 10)

  // I need to build the LINQ query with "ands" and "ors" based on the i's in this foreach
}
```

Comment: How can you tell what the scope of each AND and OR is?  you do you just want to chain them (which may be faulty logic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the Dynamic LINQ library to accomplish exactly what you're trying to do (found here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

You can use something like:

```
var finalResults = results.Where("Your where clause");
```

where "Your where clause" is the string containing your dynamically-generated where clause.

Answer (score 1):

The naive approach would be to chain calls to the `Where` method, but that way you can only achieve the AND behavior

Check out the [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) class by Joseph Albahari. It allows to build dynamic Linq queries with the OR operator